# Using Threads to perform operations on same jframe

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

i need to develop java code to have JFrame with a text filed and button.Using Threads,i need to update time for every one minute in the title bar of JFrame.Using Another Thread i need to display textbox value in the console when a button is clicked.I have code for performing both operations (updating time for every min and getting text box value)but i dont know how to add two threads  in same class.if anyone knows pls help me out

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the second thread, but you've not provided any sample code. I would, highly, recommend that you ditch your first thread in favour of a javx.swing.Timer, which will call its associated ActionListener within the context of the EDT

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is a dangerous thing to do in `Swing`.  `Swing` components are not `thread-safe` and should only be updated from the `Event Dispatching Thread` (also known as the `EDT` or Swing Thread).  To do this, `Swing` has utility methods such as `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)` which will execute the code in the Runnable (at some point in the future) on the `EDT`.  The idea is that you place your code to do Swing-things (like update the Title of the `JFrame` with the time) inside of a separate `Runnable` and pass it to `invokeLater()`.

To do this, you can create an anonymous Runnable class:

```
Runnable updateJFrame = new Runnable () {
    public void run () {
        myJFrame.setTitle("My New Title");
    }
};

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(updateJFrame);
```

Using `invokeLater()` also ensures that the components get refreshed/repainted properly after they have been updated.  (The behavior you are seeing when using statics may actually be a refresh/repaint issue.)  The moral of this story is that if you manipulate Swing components on a non-EDT thread, all bets are off.

Comment: I'd recommend using a javax.swing.Timer over a Thread for performing regularly scheduled event